# 'data:,' in the address bar while using chromedriver 2.19 and selenium 2.47

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Issue Description:

- When I'm starting the test I see `data:,` in the chrome address bar and after few seconds the Chrome window get closed instead of starting navigating to the URL.

OS & Chrome info:

- ChromeDriver:- 2.19
- Chrome:- 44.0.2403.157
- Selenium:- 2.47
- Windows 7: 32 bit.

Steps to reproduce:

- Running simple test that is trying to navigate a web page using 
  `driver.get(...)` method.

Once the test is started, the console displays the below mentioned message

> "Starting ChromeDriver 2.19.333243
>   (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 56002 Only local
>   connections are allowed."

Later, I see `data:,` in the Chrome address bar and it just keeps loading for more than 10 minutes but does not navigate to the given URL.

Comment: What URL are you trying to navigate to? What happens if you use just "http://www.google.com"? Please try a few things like this and then come back and post what you tried to solve the problem and what errors, etc. you got so we can help you better.

Comment: The code is        
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Javalibs\\Selenium\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();

Comment: The exception i receive in the console is
[604.166][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
(Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.157)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP2 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 605.09 seconds

Comment: Please add these comments to the original question so that others will be more likely to see and read them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I had mixed up my type definitions. Instantiate your driver as follows.

```
package BDDTest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {
    private ChromeDriver driver; //DOUBLE CHECK THIS BIT!! 
    private String browserName;
    private String browserVersion;

    //adjust for your own path\to\chromedriver.exe
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\cuke-jvm-dependencies\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        browserName = "Chrome";
        browserVersion = "46";

        System.out.println("Automated test run. We’re running on "+browserName+" "+browserVersion);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void goToHomePage() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.ca");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'data:,' URL is just the default address that chromedriver navigates to when launching chrome. So this by itself doesn't necessarily mean that anything is going wrong. Just remember to add the protocol - i.e. "http://".

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159684/chrome-opens-with-data-with-selenium#answer-42737737) should help. Just update the `chromedriver` and it'll work.