# Chrome opens with "Data;" with selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, ui-automation

I am a newbie to Selenium and trying to open localhost:3000 page from Chrome via selenium driver. 
The code is :

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class SeleniumTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
        driver.get("localhost:3000");
    }

}
```

However, this opens my chrome window with a "data;" . 
The chrome version is 50.0.2661.94

Any idea what is the exact issue?

Comment: what it returns if u paste in chrome localhost:3000 manually?

Comment: if someone has the same problem while using file path, do not forget to append "file:///" before the path `driver.get("file:///path/to/index.html")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Specify the protocol you are using, so instead of `localhost:3000`, use `http://localhost:3000`. If that doesn't help, see the comment [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=733#c21) on the Chromium issue tracker.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will start with data. After data just try to give the URL.The 'data:,' URL is just the default address that chromedriver navigates to when launching chrome. So this by itself doesn't necessarily mean that anything is going wrong.

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class SeleniumTests {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=KxAzV8-KEJPT8gfT0IWYAw");
}

}
```

It will open successfully. Reply if you have any query. Happy Learning.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same issue. I updated ChromeDriver to [the latest version](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and that fixed it.

Comment: You could at least indicate the version you updated to, so anyone interested in this can compare.

Comment: I am using Chrome Driver 2.28 which Supports Chrome version 55-57. Link for the downloading Chrome Driver is https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: For me Chromedriver version 2.32 with chrome version 59 worked

Comment: It looks like they fixed it again in ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96.

Comment: The driver version should match the browser one if you are testing locally in live mode. Sometimes upstream repo's like npm or brew fall behing, so in case download the latest-greatest [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads))

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using [latest release of ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (as for now it's 2.28). I had same problem with `data:,`. By mistake I've downloaded old version and got the issue with specified URL not being opened, just `data:,`

Answer (score 1):

I've been running in a similar situation, the fix in my case was simply to **upgrade chrome webdriver** to its latest version (*in my case V2.27*).

The cause of showing `Data;` instead of the real application URL was that:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<host>:<port>/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
```

failed to get created. Instead, `driver` object was holding a `null` value.

So after chrome driver upgrade , it had been created correctly and problem solved.

Hope this helps who's still stuck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Codeception, start the test with :

`$I->amOnPage('/');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two things to run :

First - you should use `http://localhost:3000`

Second - You must use debug port before creating webDriver as : `options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9225");`

Whole Code:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9225");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Drop comments if you have any query

Comment: When `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()` is called it loads in an inbuilt chrome driver:
        `/home/{user}/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/102.0.5005.61/chromedriver`
        In my case I need 101 which I loaded in  `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Path.of("").toAbsolutePath().toString()+ File.separator+"Drivers"+File.separator+"chromedriver");` instead - also in my case the rest was not needed

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me when using selenium grid with python and was caused by something different than the other answers suggest (in my case at least).

It turns out there was a runtime exception being raised after the driver object was being created (and connecting to chrome) but before it was being instructed to navigate to a URL. This all runs on a celery task queue so it was easy for me to miss. So if updating the chrome driver doesn't work, double check that you're navigating to a URL correctly and there's no errors etc.

For example:

```py
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://<ip>:4444/wd/hub",
    )

# a function here raised a runtime exception, causing chrome to launch
# but sit there with the default URL "data;/"

driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The advice I got here did not help. Eventually I figured out that putting this:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");`

at start of my test-script, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was just solved by adding `https://` to the start of my URL.

Answer (score -1):

just replace the "chromedriver.exe" with [latest release of ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).