# Selenium Chromedriver opens with data:, in navigation bar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

if i open Chrome via chromedriver and navigate to a URL i only get a data:, in the navigation bar. All googled solutions (right chromedriverversion, protocoll in URL, etc.) didnt help me.

```
package de.vhv.selenium;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OpenChromeAndNavigate {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://vhventw//selenium//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.de");
    }

}
```

In addition everything works if i add --headless and listen to the debugport. But i dont want to let it run headless.

```
 package de.vhv.selenium;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class OpenChromeAndNavigate {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://vhventw//selenium//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(getDesiredCapabilities());
        driver.get("https://www.google.de");
    }

    private ChromeOptions getDesiredCapabilities() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();


        options.addArguments("--headless");
//        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
//        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
//        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
//        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9223");


        return options;
    }

}
```

Any ideas what i can try?

Setup:

Chrome Version = 71.0.3578.80

Chromedriver Version = 2.46.628402

Comment: Did you try just passing the default ChromeOptions without any options set?

Comment: This seems to discuss the same issue. You might find an answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159684/chrome-opens-with-data-with-selenium

Comment: @Stephan : Could you please update your chrome driver to latest

Comment: Our Chromeversion is 71.0.3578.80 and i cant change it. The downloadpage (http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) says use chromedriver 2.46 with chrome 71. Should i still try chromedriver 74.0.3729.6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, that the line

options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9225");

fixed my problem. I already used it in headless runs to listen to the port and watch the headless run. But it fixed my problem with headfull runs.

```
return new ChromeDriver(getDesiredCapabilities());



private ChromeOptions getDesiredCapabilities() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9225");

    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- Not sure about your *project structure* but I will suggest to avoid the **`.`** character and the word **`selenium`** within the *package name* as in:

  ```
  package de.vhv.selenium;
  ```
- The *Value* part passed through `System.setProperty()` line containing the *absolute path* of *chromedriver.exe* should be expressed through *escaped backslashes* as:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\vhventw\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```
- As per [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads):

> If you are using *Chrome version 72*, please download *ChromeDriver 2.46* or *ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69*

- As per best practices:

  - Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u202**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
  - Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
  - Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
  - Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt))
  - *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
  - If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
  - Take a *System Reboot*.
  - Execute your `@Test`.
  - Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue, then I realised that I forgot to start the test with :

$I->amOnPage('/');

definitely to try before digging deeper.